# Is it possible to buy a domain and have it redirect to another URL?

Tags: domains, redirects, domain-registration

I am trying to set up a wedding website on a website called ewedding. I can design it using the templates I'm given there. If someone wants to visit the website, they have to visit `https://app.ewedding.com/example.com`.

Is there any way I can purchase a domain `example.com`, such that it redirects to `https://app.ewedding.com/example.com`.  If so, how?   Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service provider suggests the following:

> Free accounts use the eWedding URL you chose at signup while upgraded
>   Premium accounts may have chosen a custom .com. Even if you are using
>   a custom domain name, your original eWedding URL will still work.
>   [Source](https://ewedding.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203710065-Website-Address-URL-)

However there is a way as you have described to purchase a domain name `example.com` and set up a webpage containing a frame redirect to `https://app.ewedding.com/example.com`. In order to do that you 'll need to create a webpage at `example.com/index.html` with this code here:

```
<html><head><title>Title of your webpage</title></head>
<frameset cols="*">
 <frame name="main" src="https://app.ewedding.com/example.com " scrolling="auto" noresize>
 <noframes>
 <body>

 Your browser does not support frames

 </body>
 </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

This method is called Frame Forwarding or Cloaked / Masked / Stealth Web Redirection. Many domain name registrars provide this option without necessity of obtaining an actual hosting and having the above coding done. 
You should also carefully read terms and conditions of this ewedding app service in case such a way of using it is not legally allowed.

Comment: Couldn't you just forward the new domain to the existing domain using HTACCESS?

Comment: Yes, one could just forward url using .htaccess RedirectPermanent or even CNAME DNS record. In both cases a user would see the long service provider's url at the address bar of their browser, while using frame redirect the address bar would show `http://example.com`, which may be what one wanted when purchasing a nice domain name. On the other hand frame forwarding has its drawbacks too - SEO is an issue, for instance.

Comment: But speaking of this particular situation with a wedding page, I believe you would want the website online only for a short period of time and for a small circle of people with whom you would share its domain name. If so SEO should not be of any concern.

Answer (score 1):

Any good domain reseller should allow you to purchase a domain name and set up a redirect right there in your control panel.

For example, you are given this option at hover.com.

[image]